# Remove a page filter from a drill through

Tags: powerbi

On a table of multiple columns, three columns form a hierarchical relationship:

```
Award Code (example: 505115)
Major Class code (example: 12XX)
Class Code (example: 1230)
```

[image]

There are three more columns: budget, actuals, and available budget (shown above).

On the second page of report, drill through is enabled and there are page filters:

```
Award Code
Major Class Code
Class Code
```

On this page, there is a table. If I click 1230 (red underline) on the first page of report and drill through to the second page, this is how the table looks like:

[image]

It is easy to see that this visual has three filters:

[image]

How can I remove the Class Code filter from this table, so that it displays all classes under a given Major Class Code. Using the above example, this is what I would like to have for the table:

[image]

**UPDATE**

This is the sample.pbix file in Dropbox

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vql16lyq40iccny/sample.pbix?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new calculated table

   Drill Table = data
2. On destination page, remove your old visual and create a new table visual using the fields from the new calculated table above.
3. Create a drill measure

   Drill Measure =

   VAR a = SELECTEDVALUE(data[Major Class Code])

   VAR b = SELECTEDVALUE('Drill Table'[Major Class Code])

   RETURN IF(a = b, 1)
4. Add the drill measure to the visual filter as follows.

[image]

[Sample Link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3fa5d731a9502a3c5c443a469787895720220727160854/51d735)

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH, @David! I tested your file and now I understand everything you said. I also applied your solution to my report and it works like a charm! Again, millions of thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It is not an ideal solution but definitely works if you have this specific requirement.

Comment: I noticed an issue with the data. The same Major Class Code can be used under more than one Award Code. So I modified your measure like the following, but the table rows don't seem show correctly. `VAR c = SELECTEDVALUE(data[Award Code])
VAR d = SELECTEDVALUE('Drill Table'[Award Code])
RETURN IF(a = b && c = d, 1)`

Comment: Your logic is right and it works fine for me. There must be something else going on.

Comment: I updated the sample file via the link in the post. I added one line with Award Code being `505125 - Other`. Using the updated drill measure doesn't seem working. I can't figure out why. Thanks.

Comment: It is because you have repeated values in your hierarchy with no unique key. An easy fix is to just add Drill Table Award Code to your table on the destination page. You can hide the column if you don't want it to show but that will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I also found out that adding Award Code to the table is the solution. Otherwise, the updated Drill Measure wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't clear the drill through filters but you can work around it with a little trick. You create duplicate columns for award, major and class and you use those for your visual on your drill through page instead of the ones passed through in the filters on the drill through from your originating page. You need a measure to recreate the filter context you desire on your drill through page. Here is a video showing how to do it. If you have a sample .pbix, I can show you exact steps.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frC3B_Dk3T8

Comment: I have updated the post with a link to the sample pbix file. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: I'll add another answer to show the steps.